# Java - What is the proper way to convert a UTF-8 String to binary?

Tags: java, utf-8, binary

I'm using this code to convert a UTF-8 `String` to binary:

```java
public String toBinary(String str) {
    byte[] buf = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        int ch = (int) buf[i];
        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(ch);
        result.append(("00000000" + binary).substring(binary.length()));
        result.append(' ');
    }
    return result.toString().trim();
}
```

Before I was using this code:

```java
private String toBinary2(String str) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int ch = (int) str.charAt(i);
        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(ch);
        if (ch<256)
           result.append(("00000000" + binary).substring(binary.length()));
        else {
           binary = ("0000000000000000" + binary).substring(binary.length());
           result.append(binary.substring(0, 8));
           result.append(' ');
           result.append(binary.substring(8));
        }
        result.append(' ');
    }
    return result.toString().trim();
}
```

These two method can return different results; for example:

```java
toBinary("è") = "11000011 10101000"
toBinary2("è") = "11101000"
```

I think that because the bytes of `è` are negative while the corresponding `char` is not (because char is a 2 byte unsigned integer).
What I want to know is: which of the two approaches is the correct one and why? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, you need to understand there's no such thing as "A UTF-8 string" in Java. All strings are (at least conceptually) sequences of UTF-16 code units. Your `toBinary2` method isn't performing any UTF-8 encoding at all, which is why it's incorrect. You need to separate out the two parts of your code, at least in your mind: 1) Converting a string into binary data (`byte[]`), e.g. with `getBytes`. 2) Converting that binary data into a textual binary representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to convert text into binary data (or into text representing binary data, as you do here) you have to use *some encoding*.

Your `toBinary` uses UTF-8 for that encoding.

Your `toBinary2` uses something that's not a standard encoding: it encodes every UTF-16 codepoint <sup>*</sup> <= 256 in a single byte and all others in 2 bytes. Unfortunately that one is not a useful encoding, since for decoding you'll have to know if a single byte is stand-alone or part of a 2-byte sequence (UTF-8/UTF-16 do that by indicating with the highest-level bits which one it is).

**tl;dr** `toBinary` seems correct, `toBinary2` will produce output that can't uniquely be decoded back to the original string.

<sup>* You might be wondering where the mention of UTF-16 comes from: That's because all `String` objects in Java are implicitly encoded in UTF-16. So if you use `charAt` you get UTF-16 codepoints (which just so happen to be equal to the Unicode code number for all characters that fit into the Basic Multilingual Plane).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet might help.

```
String s = "Some String";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
for(byte b:bytes){
    int val =b;
    for(int i=;i<=s.length;i++){
        binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        val<<=1;
    }
}
System.out.println(" "+s+ "to binary" +binary);
```